# Inject a username into IE 6/7 when Auto-complete is disabled by Admin

Tags: internet-explorer, autocomplete

My work desktop does not allow me to save user names and passwords in IE (it is disabled within IE-Options-Content-AutoComplete Settings).  I would like my computer to remember my username (not my password as I am well aware that this is a security issue).  Is there a way for me to inject my user name somewhere so IE 6/7 will be able to pre-populate the name into login pop-ups?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a password manager software such as [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) to track your username/passwords for you. I know that keepass even has a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/keepass_portable) that you can keep on a thumb drive so your passwords are only available to you.

Most password management software of this nature will have the option of copying the data to the form for you. Another option is [RoboForm](http://www.roboform.com/), but that isn't free software and may violate company policy if used. There may be free and/or open source alternatives to RoboForm, but I haven't had the need to look into them since I prefer KeePass myself.

**EDIT:** Any chance of browsing with something other than IE? Even if those settings are hard coded in IE from policy settings, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, or another free browser may still allow password saving in them since the policies usually don't affect those browsers. I know at my workplace IE is necessary due to the MS web based tech being used, and that may be the scenario here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's not quite what I'm looking for though.  I would like a permanent way to keep a single user-name in the pop-up login dialog for my corporate sites that I access dozens of times each day.  I am hoping someone knows how to modify the file/registry entry that contains the listing of login details for the IE login popup box.

Comment: Updated answer to include possible non-IE related options

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm in the same position - IE is required for many of these sites.  I happily use Chrome for everything else.